# Find the number of 4-digit integers with digit sum 4?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer is $20$. But I would like to know why?

Here is the answer: If the digit sum of the desired integers is $4$, then it can be formed only from the following five multisets of digits: $[4,0,0,0]$, $[3,1,0,0]$, $[2,2,0,0]$, $[2,1,1,0]$, and $[1,1,1,1]$. The quadruples $[4,0,0,0]$ and $[1,1,1,1]$ give only one 4-digit number each, while from $[3,1,0,0]$ we obtain $2*P_{0}(2,1) = 6$ integers, and $[2,2,0,0]$ gives $P_{0}(2,1)=3$ integers; the multiset $[2,1,1,0]$, finally, gives rise to $P_{0}(2,1) + P(3) = 9$ integers. The total number f 4-digit integers with digit sum 4 is therefore $20$.

Note that $P_{0}(a,b,c) = \frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!b!c!}$ is the arrangements with repetitions, while $P$ is the permutation.

My question is: How $[4,0,0,0]$ happens to be $1$? e.g. I have $4+0+0+0$ or $0+4+0+0$, etc. So it should be $4$ integers. How is it true that $[3,1,0,0]$ is $2*P_0(2,1)$, but not $P_0(2,1,1)$? The same for $[3,1,0,0]$ and $[2,2,0,0]$. Can you explain the answer in different way.

Thank you!

Comment: "My question is: How [4,0,0,0] happens to be 1?"  Your "0+4+0+0" does not correspond to a four-digit integer.

Comment: For $[3, 1, 0, 0]$, the first $2$ represents the number of choices for the first (nonzero digit).  Once that number has been chosen, there are three positions left to fill, two of which will be filled with zeros and the other of which will be filled with the remaining nonzero digit.  This can be done in $P_0(2, 1)$ ways.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you! It is clear now. if you write your comment as answer, I will accept it. (Also, Thanks to David G. Stork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Find the number of four-digit positive integers with digit sum $4$.

**The book's method:**

Using digits $4, 0, 0, 0$:  The four must be placed in the the thousands place and each of the remaining places must be filled with a zero.  There is $1$ such number.

*Using digits* $3, 1, 0, 0$:  Choose which of the nonzero digits will be placed in the thousands place.  Choose which of the remaining three places will be filled with the other nonzero digit.  The remaining two digits must be filled with zeros.  There are $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1} = 6$$ such numbers.  Note that using the multinomial coefficient, we can express this in the form $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1, 2} = \frac{2!}{1!1!} \cdot \frac{3!}{1!2!} = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$$
where $\binom{3}{1, 2}$ represents the number of ways of filling the hundreds, tens, and units places with one nonzero digit and two zeros.

*Using digits* $2, 2, 0, 0$:  We must place a $2$ in the thousands place.  Choose which of the remaining three positions will receive a $2$.  The remaining two digits must be filled with a zero.  There are 
$$\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{1} = 3$$
such numbers.  Using multinomial coefficients, we can express this in the form
$$\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{1, 2} = \frac{1!}{1!0!} \cdot \frac{3!}{1!2!} = 3$$
where $\binom{3}{1, 2}$ represents the number of ways of filling the hundreds, tens, and units places with one nonzero digit and two zeros.

*Using digits* $2, 1, 1, 0$:  We consider two cases: the thousands place is filled by a $2$, or the thousands case is filled by a $1$.

The thousands place is filled by a $2$:  There is one way to fill the thousands place.  Choose two of the remaining three positions for the $1$s.  The zero must be placed in the remaining position.  There are $$\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{2} = 3$$ such numbers.  Using multinomial coefficients, we may write $$\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{2,1} = \frac{1!}{1!0!} \cdot \frac{3!}{2!1!} = 3$$ 
where $\binom{3}{2, 1}$ represents the number of ways of filling the hundreds, tens, and units places with two ones and one zero.

The thousands place is filled by a $1$:  There is one way to fill the thousands place.  The remaining three digits are distinct.  They can be placed in the remaining three positions in $3! = 6$ ways.  There are $$\binom{1}{1}3! = 6$$ such numbers.  Using multinomial coefficients, we may write $$\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{1,1,1} = \frac{1!}{1!0!} \cdot \frac{3!}{1!1!1!} = 6$$
where $\binom{3}{1, 1, 1}$ represents the number of ways of filling the hundreds, tens, and units places with three distinct digits.

*Using digits* $1, 1, 1, 1$:  All four positions must be filled with $1$s.  There is $\binom{4}{4} = 1$ such number.

*Total*:  There are $1 + 6 + 3 + 3 + 6 + 1 = 20$ four-digit positive integers with digit sum $20$.

**An alternative approach:**  Let $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ denote, respectively, the digit in the thousands, hundreds, tens, and units places.  Since the number has digit sum $4$,
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 4 \tag{1}$$
where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are integers satisfying $x_1 \geq 1$, $x_2 \geq 0$, $x_3 \geq 0$, $x_4 \geq 0$.

To make life simpler, we let $x_1' = x_1 - 1$. Then $x_1'$ is a nonnegative integer, like $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$.  Substituting $x_1' + 1$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 4\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 3 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation 2 corresponds to the placement of $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in a row of three ones.  For instance, 
$$1 + 1 + 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1' = x_2 = x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 0$ (and the number $2110$ since $x_1 = x_1' + 1$), while 
$$+ + 1 1 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1' = x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 0$ (and the number $1030$).  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can place three addition signs in a row of three ones, which is 
$$\binom{3 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{6}{3} = 20$$
since we must choose which three of the six positions required for three ones and three addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Notice that we obtained the same answer as above without doing casework.

Comment: +1. Thank you so much, the second method is really faster and better for general cases.Thank you again for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) (this is equivalent to N.F. Taussig's last approach, but isn't identified as such).  The equivalence is as follows: Put four stars in a row.  Three bars are interposed in this sequence to divide it into four regions, each of which represents one of the digits.

We now have a sequence of four stars and three bars.  If we assume that the first digit of the number must be non-zero, then the first bar cannot appear before the first star, but is otherwise free to go wherever.  In other words, the six symbols after the first star may appear in any order, so long as they contain three stars and three bars.  Therefore, the number of permissible sequences is

$$
\binom{3+3}{3} = \binom{6}{3} = 20
$$